# Removing files from your Git history exclusively between two commits

Tags: git

I am trying to remove a number of large files from my history using `filter-branch`. I have used this command before with success but I'm currently having trouble for a particular edge case.

The problem is that these large files were never truly removed but ***replaced by smaller versions with the same path***.

As far as I can tell, I believe I have a unique problem.

### Git Log

To elaborate, here is a rudimentary representation of my repo:

```
----- A ------ B ----------- HEAD
```

where:

```
A is the commit where the large files were introduced
B is the commit (about 30 later) where the large files were replaced with smaller ones
HEAD is thousands of commits forward of B (~2 years of active development)
```

### Git Filter-Branch

In theory, I should be able to do something like this:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch filenames' <parent of A>..B
```

I believe I should use `<parent of A>` because `filter-branch` is not inclusive. (I'm not sure if I also need to use the parent of B also but this is the least of my worries right now).

Running this gives me the error:

```
$ git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch filenames' <parent of A>..B 
Which ref do you want to rewrite?
```

So I included `--glob="refs/heads/master*"` at the end of the command which seems to do the trick ([source](https://gist.github.com/mike-perdide/775263)).

Once execution has finished, the files have been completely removed - it seems that git ignores the upper bound that I specified.

So I'm wondering if this method is even possible?

### Alternative approaches

I thought I should list some other ideas I've had so that potential answers can be focussed on solving the problem.

1. The pragmatic approach would be to commit a filename change at HEAD and then run `git filter-branch ... HEAD`. However, my repository has a number of branches in active development and I believe this method would be very messy.
2. Another way could be to do something like what is described [here](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/removing-files-from-history-but-not-filesystem-td6523784.html). To quote: `create a temporary branch to point at HEAD^, filter-branch it, then add a graft to stitch the remaining commit on top of it, then filter-branch HEAD and then remove the graft.`

Hopefully someone has come across this problem before and can lend their expertise.

### Update

The files I want to remove total **~500MB** so I'm understandably very keen to remove them! They were committed long before I joined the company and are a remnant of our move from an internal Mercurial server to GitHub (I suppose pushing 500MB to an internal server would be less noticeable than GitHub...).

### Update 2

I've been following twalberg's second answer (I think I'm using it in the correct manner):

```
git filter-branch --index-filter '(( $(git rev-list <SHA-of-child-of-B> --not $GIT_COMMIT | wc -l) > 0 )) && git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch <filenames>'
```

This produces the kind of output I'd expect:

```
...
Rewrite dc8a4b29463bfa43c2f3efe0c6e5a29a5cc6e0ef (1071/5680)rm 'file1'
rm 'file2'
rm 'file3'
rm 'file4'
...
```

Before ending in an (expected?) error:

```
Rewrite e6b712b57257e2edd0bb9fbbac59e4c9d7b5aa79 (1072/5680)index filter failed: (( $(git rev-list e6b712b --not $GIT_COMMIT | wc -l) > 0 )) && git rm -rf --ignore-unmatch <filename>
```

Where `e6b712b` is the child of `B`.

At this point I assume everything has worked so I do a local filesystem clone of my repository to test it:

```
git clone file://<repo> <new repo>
```

The number of objects and packfile size have decreased a very small amount - I'm not sure why. By running `git count-objects -v` against the original repository versus the one that has had `filter-branch` run against it:

Original repository:

```
count: 0
size: 0
in-pack: 106640
packs: 1
size-pack: 815512
prune-packable: 0
garbage: 0
```

The `filter-branch`ed and filesystem cloned repository:

```
count: 0
size: 0
in-pack: 96165
packs: 1
size-pack: 793656
prune-packable: 0
garbage: 0
```

I'm really not sure why this still isn't working - perhaps I'm not following the suggested answer correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, if you truly want to remove those objects from your repository (compared to simply removing them from current and future revisions), `filter-branch` is the way to do that, and if you are going to rewrite commit `A`, every commit out to every branch head that includes `A` in its history must be rewritten as well, since the commit hash of a commit depends on the commit hash of every parent of that commit. If you don't rewrite all branches that include `A`, then those objects are still legitimately part of some commit in your reachable history, and they won't be pruned.

For each branch `BR` that contains `A` in it's history, this should work:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch filenames' BR --not A~1
```

which will rewrite from `A` (by pruning the branch at `A`s parent) out to the current tip of branch `BR`. It will remove the files from all those commits, though, even after they were replaced by newer smaller versions. In order to remove them only up to commit `B`, you can expand the filter script like this:

```
... --index-filter '(( $(git rev-list <SHA-of-child-of-B> --not $GIT_COMMIT | wc -l) > 0 )) && git rm ...' ...
```

This uses rev-list to list all revisions after the commit currently being rewritten and up to the child of `B`, counts those lines, and only does the `git rm` if one or more revisions fall in that range (when `$GIT_COMMIT == B`, one line will be printed - hence the need for using the child of `B`).

That's a rather large change even for a single branch, and a lot of work if you have many branches that were spawned at or after `A`, so you'll have to decide if it's ultimately worth it, or if you just need a bigger disk (you didn't mention exactly *how* big these files are).

Comment: thank you twalberg, I'm going to try this first thing tomorrow. Incidentally, I did [stumble upon](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html#_examples) the `--not` switch just after posting the question but I wasn't sure if it would work. I'll make sure to report back ASAP! Almost forgot - these files total about **500MB**! So they make a _slight_ dent on the repository size ;-)

Comment: I've been trying your second approach all morning but I just can't seem to clear the files out - I'll update my question to break down exactly what I'm seeing.

Comment: @ben.snape Saw your updates... It's not clear to me at the moment whether that failure is "normal" or not. If I get a chance, maybe I can set up a test of my own, but that may not be for several days. One thing you could do is use `gitk` (or other repo visualizer) to check to make sure a) the cloned repository topology matches the original - the branch shapes should be the same, although SHA values have obviously changed - and b) make sure the commits you expected to be rewritten look right, and perhaps some of the surrounding non-rewritten ones as well...

Answer (score 0):

```
A     is the commit where the large files were introduced
B     is the commit (about 30 later) where the large files were replaced 
      with smaller ones
HEAD  is thousands of commits forward of B (~2 years of active development)
```

You having said this I would strongly advise against `filter-branch`, as I believe it would rewrite 2 years worth of commit SHAs. Perhaps another solution would be [`git revert`](http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-revert.html)

```
git revert SHA_A..SHA_B
    Revert the changes done by commits from commit SHA_A (included) to
    SHA_B (included)
```

Comment: thanks Steven - I'm not sure if this will work in my case but I'm not discounting anything until I've tried it. Will keep you updated.